# Back and forth, removeFromSuperView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, subview

Im a bit confused...

I have a mainview, which by the click of a button shows a subview. What I want to do next is to 
be able to switch back and forth between the Main and the Sub, but when I do this, the return button FROM the subView makes the TO SubView button disabled...I cant seem to be able to access the Subview a second time. Nothing happens.

What I have is a `UIButton`, and an `IBAction`, which I have written the "`[self.view removeFromSuperView];`" in.

Please do not get me wrong here, I do get back to the mainView. The problem is that I cant go back to the subview afterwards.

I've read something in the documentation about retaining the subView...But I did not quite understand how to do it.

Could anyone please shed some light over this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is just a guess, since you don't provide much code:
- you might first need to retain the view. in case it's only retained by its current superview
`[self.view retain];`

remember to free it manually when it's no longer needed. 
`[self.view release];`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that...still no effect :( Maybe I need to implement a retain count?

Comment: retain count should not be usually used, you can make a check though: `NSLog(@"%d", [self.view retainCount]);` or `NSLog(@"%@", self.view");`. If you'll get 0 or null in the console, then you're releasing the view somewhere in the code (since you retain it before `removeFromSuperView`, there must be an explicit call to `release` or `autorelease` somewhere).

Comment: Unless you're rebuilding the subview every time, you'll have to retain it in the superview. The to button isn't working probably because your subview no longer exists the second time you try to "go to it". I'd recommend simply using subview.hidden = YES; instead of removing it. That way you don't have to deal with messy allocations and deallocations.

Comment: @XenElement The thing is, I have retained the subview, made a property and synthesize, then, in the "back button" I simply call : "[self.view removeFromSuperview];"...Is there a better way to retain the subView and then remove it? I do have what you stated first, I rebuild the subView everytime with the "iniwithNib" thing...Help? Thanks!

Comment: I think I'd recommend simply building the subview once and hiding it every time that you "go back". Just try out subview.hidden = TRUE; and subview.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE; I'm not sure how that affects the speed of your app but unless you're using every ounce of memory available for something else, then that would be the easy fix.

Comment: Just a thought, you're only removing the view from the superview, correct? Not releasing it? You shouldn't have to release it, and if you don't release it, you shouldn't need to rebuild it. If it is a property already you should be able to simply addSubview and removeFromSuperview.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try out this?

to open ur subview:

```
Ursubview *Ursubview    =[[Ursubview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
Ursubview.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:Ursubview animated:YES];
```

to go back:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you! The thing is, I have a customized viewtransition already set up, which I really want to use...[self.view insertSubview:myViewController.view belowSubview: imageWheel];; My only problem is that I want to be able to switch back on forth.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hide it instead of removing it?